# how to print the name of a tag jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to know how to print the `value="5472"`

```
<input type="hidden" class="ArticleInfo" name="Link4" value="website"/>
<input type="hidden" class="ArticleID" value="5472" />
<input type="hidden" class="SortData" value="4" />
```

Im trying this but it does not print anything what am i doing wrong?

```
Elements articleID = doc.select("td.ArticleID");
List<String>ArticleIDs = new ArrayList <String>();
for(Element Article : articleID){
    System.out.println(Article.text());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `attr("attribute name")` method to get a attribute value of a element

example

```
List<String> ArticleIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Element Article : articleID) {
    String value= Article.attr("value");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

output

```
5472
```

Comment: Still comming up blank but it is trying to print something

Comment: @Ross well for me not blank .show your entire code.post it somewhere like http://pastebin.com/ and give the link

Comment: it prints values when i change articleID to just "td" and change values to "class" how would i be able to direct to the correct tag from <td><input><ArticleID><Value>?

Comment: i didn't get your comment.explain little bit ?